# Why do we need to use BeginInvokeOnMainThread in on app loading to show DisplayAlert

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

This code is not showing `DisplayAlert`

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DisplayAlert("Hey", "Welcome", "OK");
}
```

but when I use `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` alert is getting displayed

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                DisplayAlert("Hey ", "Welcome", "OK");
            });
}
```

Is this happens with `DisplayAlert` only or with other controls as well. Can anybody tell me why does this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for that is quite simple when a constructor is called it is on a different thread than the `UIThread`, Now the UI thread is where all the changes on the UI actually occur.

**Note**

An application can have n number of different threads but only one UIThread

So when you do this:

```
public MainPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   DisplayAlert("Hey", "Welcome", "OK");
}
```

What happens is it runs on a constructor's thread(not UIThread) and hence it is executed but never shown on the UI, On the contrary when you do this:

```
public MainPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
            DisplayAlert("Hey ", "Welcome", "OK");
        });
}
```

The BeginInvokeOnMainThread method forces your display alert method to run on UI thread causing it to be visible on the UIThread.

I hope it makes sense to you,

Feel free to revert if you did not understand anything.

Good luck

Comment: Yes It is, `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` is the equivalent of iOS's `InvokeOnMainThread ` and Android's `RunOnUIThread`

Answer (score 2):

UI operations must occur on the main UI thread.  `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` forces an operation on a background thread to occur on the UI thread

Comment: Thank you. Is `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` MainUIThread? is Thread and UIThread different?

Comment: An application can have many threads, but only one UI thread.